# How to read the configuration not in the current project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-6.0

As we all know, for Web API projects created based on .NET 6.0, Visual Studio will automatically generate the `appsettings.json` configuration file, which can be read through the constructor-injected `Configuration` in the current project (dll).

So how to read the configuration that is not in the current project?

Comment: What do you mean by "another project"? Your ASP.NET application's bootup (Program/Startup class) has code that reads that file. What sort of configuration are you trying to read, and how is it stored?

Comment: There's no such thing as a project at run time. The project is the source for an application. Multiple projects can generate a single application. It's the application that matters. What is the relationship between the application and this config file and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how to read the configuration not in the current project

If you can get the relative path (Full Path), you can try the below way(In ApiAppseting  project to get the Application2  appsettings.json):

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\ApiAppseting\Application2\appsettings.json";
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile(path)
  .Build();
var precision = configuration.GetValue<string>("aa");
```

Result:
[image]